# I am trying to make a video chat app with peerjs But the prblem is that the connection between the two users is not being established

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc, peerjs

The below is the code of the server side

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const { v4: uuidV4} = require('uuid');

app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/' , (req , res)=>{
    res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`);
});

app.get('/:room' , (req , res)=>{
    console.log(req.params);
    res.render('room' , {roomId: req.params.room});
})

io.on('connection' , socket =>{
    socket.on('join-room' , (roomId , userId)=>{
        socket.join(roomId);
        socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected' , userId)
    })
})

server.listen(3000)
```

Now the code of client side javascript

```
const socket = io('/')
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  host: '/',
  port: '3001'
})
const myVideo = document.createElement('video')
myVideo.muted = true
const peers = {}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
video: true,
audio: true
}).then(stream => {
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream)

    myPeer.on('call', call => {
        call.answer(stream)
        const video = document.createElement('video')
        call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
            addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
        })
    })
    socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
       connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
   })
})

socket.on('user-disconnected', userId => {
    if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close()
})

myPeer.on('open', id => {
   socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
})

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
    const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream)
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
    })
    call.on('close', () => {
        video.remove()
    })

   peers[userId] = call
}

function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
   video.srcObject = stream
   video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
       video.play()
   })
   videoGrid.append(video)
}
```

After this i am not able to establish connections between the two users.
I am using peerjs library to connect the calls
the server is running at port 3000
and the peer is running at 3001

I am following the a video from a youTube channel webdevsimplified
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvlyzDZDEq4

Comment: I followed the same tutorial and stuck into the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I delete "broadcast" at socket.emit at line 22

```
io.on('connection' , socket =>{
    socket.on('join-room' , (roomId , userId)=>{
        socket.join(roomId);
        socket.to(roomId).emit('user-connected' , userId) //here
    })
})
```

then I run

```
peerjs --port 3001
```

at second terminal, it works fine :)

p.s my socket.io version is "^4.0.0" at server side

Answer (score 0):

Try peerjs --port 3001 in one terminal and start your server on another terminal. If this isn't the case, please elaborate what is happening exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the Peer config so its just `const myPeer = new Peer()`

It doesn't like `new Peer(undefined)`